# TN-S system neutral point earth resistance

Tags: grounding, power-engineering, fault, distribution-network

According to many sources on the internet, a secondary neutral earth resistor is added at the distribution stations (transformers) to reduce the earth fault current.

My question is when using a TN-S type of configuration (with separate protective earth [PE] line from the load to the source), on a circuit diagram, where should the neutral earth resistance be placed?

Should it come between the neutral and the PE line at the source? Or should there be no resistor installed between the neutral and the PE lines and this secondary neutral resistor is connected to the PE line at the source?

Comment: Can you check and re-read your question because it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Andyaka Can you please see if it makes sense now?

Comment: Surely you can find your answer [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=TN-S+earthing+circuit&rlz=1C1DIMC_enGB828GB828&sxsrf=ALeKk03igWHtp1amp5OIhC38T7yxmRMm1w:1589901781994&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK5sXXncDpAhXJYMAKHXBjBLkQ_AUoAXoECBUQAw&biw=1282&bih=710#imgrc=Xz8HMBYDExpcFM).

Comment: That article describes the working of a TN-S system, but it does not mention the use of a Neutral Earth Resistor, does it?

Comment: Your words - *According to many sources on the internet, a secondary neutral earth resistor is added at the distribution stations* - please link to one of those articles.

Comment: https://www.ee.co.za/article/substation-neutral-earthing.html

Comment: https://electricalnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/types-of-neutral-earthing-in-power-distribution/